Jenkins Node Restriction - Jenkins Node should be visible to specific project only
We have Jenkins setup with Multiple project(Folder). Each folder has 3 user groups: Developer, Lead, View. We need to restrict the nodes to projects, each project should be able to see only their specific node dedicated to their project
Example,
Project/Folder name - Atlassian
Groups assigned - Atlassian-Lead, Atlassian-Developer, Atlassian-View
Node - jenkins-atlassian
The members of these groups can only see thier Folder and also should see the only the node dedicated to their Project.
We tried to setup the Job Restriction Plugin,in the Job Restriction plugin we can add user groups in Node configuration. But the plugin is up for adoption and there are no recent releases.

I am not fully clear on your setup but it seems to me that you could define roles (with the Matrix-based security) to allow access to specific jobs. And give those jobs only access to specific nodes with the node label definition. This would mean splitting your current job in multiple ones.

Hi Ray, Thanks for the suggestion. We are already using the Matrix-based security plugin for project based authorization. Each folder has three user-groups added to it. we need 1 agent allocated to each folder, when i'm trying to enable the "node based secutiry" in the node configuration and adding the same groups for a particular node, other user group members are still able to run their jobs on the node. The node-based secutiry does not work as configured.

If you are not happy with the abandoned plugin you only other option is to have separate instances of jenkins, each with their own jobs, users, and nodes. There is no way to restrict every pipeline from using node('someone-elses-node'){...}. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.
